# Color.parseColor returns negative

Tags: android

I have just tried to do like

```
System.out.println("color == " + Color.parseColor("#F5F5F5"));
```

then it returns like

```
color == -657931
```

anyone knows why, please?

Comment: It return Constant Value for given Color Hash code.

Comment: the problem is it comes out with error on the code when i use like this -- >
remoteViews.setInt(MAIL, "setBackgroundResource", Color.parseColor("#F5F5F5"));

Comment: should i just put decimal number instead of parsing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First of all `parseColor` method will return an integer representation of the **hexadecimal** `F5F5F5` which is actually `FFF5F5F5` + the opacity of the color.

the decimal value of `FFF5F5F5` is `4294309365` which is then converted to integer that will overflow thus giving your that negative number.

here is an example of that overflow

```
    int i = (int)4294309365L; //4294309365L the decimal representation of FFF5F5F5
    System.out.println(i); //result: -657931
```

Comment: can you tell me how the decimal or hex is converted to integer, i'm confused i didn't get why the decimal and integer are different.

Comment: that is correct and that is why we never should convert int to string and then again to int. Every time i have try something like that to ints, colors, DateTime i get similar errors. keep the int of the color and if its a raw int convert it to color with "new Android.Graphics.Color(rawColor);"

Answer (score 5):

It does what it is supposed to, it is the int representation of #F5F5F5. [This description](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html) in the API denotes why a color can be negative while represented as an int.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#parseColor(java.lang.String)

Short explenation:

```
                     32bit integer in hex:AARRGGBB
Transparent: Constant Value: 0         (0x00000000) 
      Black: Constant Value: -16777216 (0xff000000)
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, to store a 32 bit color value (0xFFFFFFFF - color with alpha), we need 32 bits (2^32) but `Integer` on android supports a max value of 2^31-1 (https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Integer.html) by default when used unsigned and when signed, this goes up to the full 2^32 that we need, that is why parsed colors can be negative (because we need a signed integer to be able to store it). 
More at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#valueOf(float, float, float, float, android.graphics.ColorSpace)

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior from Color.parseColor()
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#parseColor(java.lang.String)

```
public static int parseColor (String colorString)
```

The method returns a integer representation of a hexadecimal color.

You can find more in the detailed documentation.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html